# How to pass a textbox value in to url parameter

Tags: php

i have some problem in here. I have textbox value inside table, and when i clicked link "Valid", i can pass the textbox value to another page. 
This is my textbox code in table

```
echo "<form name='nomor' role='form' method='get'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='nomortempat' class='form-control input-sm'></input>";
echo "</form>";
```

This is my button

```
 echo "<td class='center'>";
echo "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='validasi.php?idorder=" . $row['id_order'] . "&pilih=" . $_GET['pilih'] . "'>
<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'>Valid</i></a>
echo "</td>";
```

Maybe someone can give me a solution, Thank you and have a nice day!!

Comment: *"and when i clicked button "Valid", i can pass the textbox value to another page"* - That statement says it works.

Comment: Where's the code for your form?

Comment: Your button is not a button. That is a link. You need to write a litte jQuery snippet, or use `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

Comment: you also tagged as mysql, *why?* There's hardly anything to support the question/code posted. Oh, and you can also safely get rid of `</input>` it's an invalid closing tag.

Comment: `$var1=$_GET['idorder']; $var2=$_GET['pilih'];` ? Heck I don't know... what do you want to do here? Seems like we'll be picking at straws till the cows come home.

Comment: hey guys, my bad i have edited my question

Comment: @Rei I don't think you can send the value with get if it's not submitted. Look at my answer below. It should work. It uses sessions to send the two variables and form submit GET method with the form. Read below "EDIT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page validasi.php add this:

```
$IDorder = $_GET['idorder']; 
$Pilih = $_GET['pilih'];
```

Now you have two variables on validasi.php called IDorder and Pilih from your form

Or is it the nomortempat you want?
I think you can just add

```
$nomortempat = $_GET['nomortempat'];
```

to the validasi page and it should work. If I understand your code it should be sent

EDIT I was wrong, you need to add a sumbmit button to your form.

Add session start at the top of your pages: `session_start();`.

Then add this to your first page:

```
$_SESSION["idorder"] = $idorder;
$_SESSION["pilih"] = $pilih;
```

Then this code to your form:

```
echo "<form name='nomor' role='form' method='get'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='nomortempat' class='form-control input-sm'></input>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></input>";
echo "</form>";
```

Then on validasi page add this:

```
$nomortempat = $_GET['nomortempat']; // and:
$IDorder = $_SESSION["idorder"];
$Pilih = $_SESSION["pilih"];
```

Now you have all three values on validasi.php

Comment: Hey @Andreas Thank you for your answer, is it possible to pass textbox value without submit button?

Comment: @Rei I don't think so. I have never tried. But you can change the text of the button and I believe you can even make it a image. But as I said, I have never tried nor looked for an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

with GET form, you could try this:

```
    echo "<form name='nomor' action='action.php' role='form' method='get'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='nomortempat' class='form-control input-sm'></input>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='valid'>";
    echo "</form>";
```

and in `action.php` page, to catch value in textbox `name='nomortempat'`, code is below:

```
if (isset($_GET['nomortempat'])){
        echo $_GET['nomortempat'];
    }
```

Of course, you could add more input fields whenever you want to inside form with different names.